# ASP .NET Core 3.1 - Can not download files larger then 300 MB, server returns 0 KB files

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-mvc

I am reaching out to you to ask for your assist to solve a problem which occurred while downloading files from Microsoft SharePoint. The issue appears when large files have been downloaded (over 300MB) through ASP.NET Core 3.1 app. There is an interesting behaviour when downloading the large files. On our local side, while using IIS Express everything works as expected and we are able to download files larger than 300 MB, but when the application is hosted with IIS on a remote server after downloading the size of those files is 0 KB.

[0KB downloaded file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZPMg.png)

As you can see in the screen shot above, the file size after downloading is 0 KB, but it should be over 300 MB.
Other files which size is less than 300 MB we are able to download normally on our local side and on the remote hosted server. We are using IIS server. Lots of steps have been taken, from startup class additions, modifications in download file action, modifying settings in IIS, even editing registry editor and web.config files. In the end nothing was helpful.

```html
public async Task < FileStreamResult > DownloadFile(string serverFileUrl, string fileName) {
  var accToken = GetToken();
  var webUrl = "https://...";
  var fileUrl = serverFileUrl;
  var accessToken = accToken.Result.ToString();
 
  using(var client = new HttpClient()) {
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
    var requestUrl = String.Format("{0}/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/$value", webUrl, fileUrl);
    var response = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    var fileContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
 
    return File(fileContent, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName, true);
  }
}
```

Can you advise us how to solve this problem? Maybe there exist some additional configurations or some framework limit.

Comment: You need to increase this value in IIS.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PpiB.png

Comment: I tried increasing that value but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: have someone found the solution please?

Comment: @A.Ghaffar sadly nothing new on this, still not figured out how to solve this problem

Comment: @Anel: somehow it is related to server configuration. We have solved the problem by adding web.config in core application. In web.config, set
hostingModel="outofprocess"
maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" (for around 1 GB)